# GIT - Compile and Test Staging Area

Tags: git, version-control

I am using `GIT` and I am working on 2 tasks at the same time. Task 1 and Task2. Now I want to push to the server Task1. So I commit all related files of Task 1 (T1) to the staging area.

My Staging area its ready to be pushed to the server, but before doing this, I consider it would be safe to check if my staging area its compiling and passing the tests.

How can I get a working dir with the staging area `only changes in order to compile it` and run the automated tests?

**Note I dont want to run tests of the working directory, only of the staging area...Because working dir has changes related from T1 and T2.**

Answer (score 7):

You could `git stash save` to save all of your non-related changes into a stash, run your tests, then restore the non-related changes with `git stash pop`. (If it were me, I would first read **man git-stash** to ensure I got all of the steps in the right order.)

Comment: To be precise, what you need in this case is `git stash save --keep-index`, which keeps the staged code intact while stashing the local modification only.

Comment: But be careful if you have untracked files, i.e. files not added to Git yet. These will not be stashed and so you won't realize if a new file is needed for compiling but not yet added to revision control. Use the `--include-untracked`switch to also stash those away: `git stash save -k -u`.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds to me like you should be using git branches. Each of your tasks would be developed on a separate branch and you can push one before the other, and merge up from the first completed branch (task) to the second.

See [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) for more details.

Comment: Yes I know. But I just would like to know what would happen in this case I have mentioned...

Comment: Yes, in some cases using branches is the correct answer, but not always. For example, you may want to exclude some debugging code from being staged and committed, and test whether the staged code builds and runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

i have a similar project. i use branches to achieve this. i created a `src` branch and code there. once everything seems ok i commit then branch off that point to a `bin` branch. if compiling works i commit it. then i merge the `src` branch into `master`. this methodology keeps the `master` branch clean with only known working code. and keeps the dev code and compiled files in their own autonomous branches (which i never push).